# Is it possible for VS code to detect a templated inherited base class member inside the methods of a templated derived class?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, templates, inheritance, intellisense

Say for example I have the following base and derived templated classes.

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct base {
  T value;
  base() : value(7) {}
};

template <typename base_t = base<float>>
struct derived : public base_t {
  derived() : base_t() {
  }
  void display() {
    std::cout << "value = " << this->value << "\n";
  }
};
```

If I instantiate them in the main function then VS code can detect the appropriate members and methods.

[image: VS code showing the members of the derived and base class]

But when accessing the member of the base class from the derived class methods, it cannot find the value member of the base class.

[image: VS code not showing the members of the base class in it methods]

I wonder if there is a way to do so?

Comment: I'm not sure, but this might be a dup of https://stackoverflow.com/q/75348919/11107541. check it out and see if it is.

Comment: As `base_t` can be anything, your expected suggestion might be wrong...

Comment: Even if I don't think intellisense implements suggestion based on concept yet.